# How to execute results of dbms_output.put_line

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, execute-immediate

There is a table contains this kind of data: `select to_char(sysdate,'day') from dual` in a column. I want to get results of the every query that the table keeps.

My result set should be the result of `select to_char(sysdate,'day') from dual` query. So in this case it is a **tuesday**.

SO_SQL_BODY is Varchar2.

I wrote this code but it returns only table data.

```
CREATE  or replace PROCEDURE a_proc
AS

 CURSOR var_cur IS

select  SO_SQL_BODY FROM SO_SUB_VARS group by SO_SQL_BODY;

var_t  var_cur%ROWTYPE;

   TYPE var_ntt IS TABLE OF var_t%TYPE;

var_names  var_ntt;
BEGIN
OPEN  var_cur;
FETCH var_cur BULK COLLECT INTO var_names;
CLOSE var_cur;

FOR indx IN 1..var_names.COUNT LOOP

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(var_names(indx).SO_SQL_BODY);

END LOOP;
END a_proc;
```

Comment: Can you share the table data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE
   res varchar2(4000);
   sql_str varchar2(1000);
BEGIN
  FOR r IN
    (select  SO_SQL_BODY FROM SO_SUB_VARS  WHERE SO_SQL_BODY IS NOT NULL
  )
  LOOP
     sql_str := r.SO_SQL_BODY;
     EXECUTE immediate sql_str INTO res;
     dbms_output.put_line(sql_str);
     dbms_output.put_line('***********************');
     dbms_output.put_line(res);
     dbms_output.put_line('***********************');
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Try this - iterate to not null records - execute them and print the result.This script works supposing the fact that SO_SQL_BODY contains a query which projects only one column.Also if the projection is with more than two columns then try to use a refcursor and dbms_sql package

Answer (score 0):

İf `var_names(indx).SO_SQL_BODY` output is a runnable sql text;

```
CREATE  or replace PROCEDURE a_proc
AS

 CURSOR var_cur IS

select  SO_SQL_BODY FROM SO_SUB_VARS group by SO_SQL_BODY;

var_t  var_cur%ROWTYPE;

   TYPE var_ntt IS TABLE OF var_t%TYPE;

var_names  var_ntt;
BEGIN
OPEN  var_cur;
FETCH var_cur BULK COLLECT INTO var_names;
CLOSE var_cur;

FOR indx IN 1..var_names.COUNT LOOP

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(var_names(indx).SO_SQL_BODY);
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE var_names(indx).SO_SQL_BODY;
END LOOP;
END a_proc;
```

Comment: It gives an error.    ORA-06535: statement string in EXECUTE IMMEDIATE is NULL or 0 length

Comment: Do 'var_names(indx).SO_SQL_BODY' this statement return a executable sql text?

Comment: I don't thinks so. It is a table has two columns and the column  that keeps 'select to_char(sysdate,'day') from dual'  kind of datas, type is varchar2.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a full cursor for this example. An implicit one would make it a lot shorter.

```
create or replace procedure a_proc is
        lReturnValue varchar2(250);
    begin
        for q in (select so_sql_body from so_sub_vars group by so_sql_body)
        loop

            execute immediate q.so_sql_body into lReturnValue;
            dbms_output.put_line(lReturnValue);

        end loop;
    end a_proc;
```

You should add an exception handler that will care for cases where there is a  bad SQL query in your table. Also note that executing querys saved in a database table is your entry point to SQL injection.